# Bootstrap Open/Collapse not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open div which is inside the div.

My second div is not opening, in fact, the first div is closing.

Try to click Part 1 then The div under it.

I want that div to be open when clicking on it, but it is closing the part1 div

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<center><strong>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
 <div class="panel panel-default"  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#part1"> <!--Date of Birth-->
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          Part 1
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="part1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
  
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1.1">
 <div class="panel panel-default"  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1.1" href="#1.1"> <!--Date of Birth-->
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          ऑडियो नंबर 15 छह काय के जीव
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="1.1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
  <audio controls="controls">
    <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1HMEmwK4COifRjhe8IWM82Pn5tw3UO4xs"> 
</audio>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</strong></center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `part1` div and its children outside the `accordion` div. And I renamed your `1.1` div to `one` because id's shouldn't begin with a number.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<center>
<strong>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#part1">
            <!--Date of Birth-->
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    Part 1
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="part1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1.1">
                <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1.1" href="#one">
                    <!--Date of Birth-->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            ऑडियो नंबर 15 छह काय के जीव
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="one" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <audio controls="controls">
                                <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1HMEmwK4COifRjhe8IWM82Pn5tw3UO4xs">
                            </audio>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</strong>
</center>
```